# How to add more parameter on controller laravel mail

Tags: laravel, mailer

I want to send email using Laravel and success with this code

```
Mail::to($email)->send(new SendMail($name))
```

Now I want to send more parameter like subject with this code, but didn't work.
No error message but email not being sent.

```
Mail::send(new SendMail($name function($message) use ($email){
    $message->to($email)->subject('Verify your Account');
}));
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#writing-mailables) didn't help? "_All of a mailable class' configuration is done in the build method. Within this method, you may call various methods such as from, subject, view, and attach to configure the email's presentation and delivery._"

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that

```
   $template = 'view.email';
   $paramets = ['data'=>$data];//Your to value to print in email
   $email = 'to@email.com'// to email 
   $cc = 'cc@email.com' // or null
   $toName = 'John Doe' // or null
   $subject = 'Verify your Account';

   Mail::send($template, $parameters, function($message) use($email,$cc,$toName,$subject) {
    $message->from(env('sender'), env('nameSender'));
    if($cc) $message->cc($cc);
    $message->to($email, $toName)
                ->subject($subject);
   });
```

I am using a generic method. So i can use this method to all emails that i need to send